# InfoBox Code - Missing Object error

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

Using [Google Maps V3 (PHP/MYSQL with custome infobox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865872/google-maps-v3-php-mysql-with-custome-infobox), I've put together the code (below) to try and implement the InfoBox code into one of my maps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Map My Finds - All Locations</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/alllocationsstyle.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var customIcons = {
            0: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            },
            1: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            }
            };

 function load() { 
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), { 
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.312195845815246,-4.45948481875007), 
            zoom:6, 
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap' 
            }); 

    // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file 
    downloadUrl("phpfile.php", function(data) { 
        function createMarker(markerXML) { 
            var locationname = markerXML.getAttribute("locationname"), 
            address = markerXML.getAttribute("address"),
            totalfinds = markerXML.getAttribute("totalfinds"),
            lat = parseFloat(markerXML.getAttribute("osgb36lat")),                
            lng = parseFloat(markerXML.getAttribute("osgb36lon")),

            icon = {}; 
            if (totalfinds == 0) {   
            icon = customIcons[0]; 
            } else if (totalfinds >= 1) {   
            icon = customIcons[1];      
            } 
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
                    map: map, 
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng), 
                    icon: icon.icon, 
                    shadow: icon.shadow 
                }), 

                boxText = document.createElement("div"); 

            boxText.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 8px; background: yellow; padding: 5px;"; 
            boxText.innerHTML = locationname + "<p>" + 'No. of finds: ' + "<b>" + totalfinds + "</b>" + "</p>";

            var myOptions = { 
                content: boxText, 
                disableAutoPan: false, 
                maxWidth: 0, 
                pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0), 
                zIndex: null, 
                boxStyle: { 
                    background: "url('tipbox.gif') no-repeat", 
                    opacity: 0.75, 
                    width: "280px" 
                }, 
                closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px", 
                closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif", 
                infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1), 
                isHidden: false, 
                pane: "floatPane", 
                enableEventPropagation: false 
            }; 

            var infoBox = new InfoBox(myOptions); 

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () { 
                    infoBox.open(map, marker); 
                } 
      ); 
        } 

        var xml = data.responseXML, 
            markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker"), 
            numMarkers = markers.length; 

        for (var i = 0; i < numMarkers; i++) { 
            createMarker(markers[i]); 
        } 
    }); 
} 
            </script> 
            </head>    
            <body onLoad="load()">
                <div id="map"></div>
            </body> 
            </html>
```

When I try and run this I get the following error: 'object expected line 29 char 5'.

Where am I going wrong?

I also would be grateful if someone could possibly give me some advice on whether there may be any debugging tools that could help me identify these types of error in the furture.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>All Locations</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/alllocationsstyle.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var customIcons = {
            0: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            },
            1: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            }
            };

            function load() { 
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), { 
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.312195845815246,-4.45948481875007), 
            zoom:6, 
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap' 
            }); 

            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

            // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file 
            downloadUrl("phpfile.php", function(data) { 
            var xml = data.responseXML; 
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
            var locationname = markers[i].getAttribute("locationname"); 
            var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
            var totalfinds = markers[i].getAttribute("totalfinds");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng( 
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("osgb36lat")), 
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("osgb36lon")));
            var html = locationname + "<p>" + 'No. of finds: ' + "<b>" + totalfinds + "</b>" + "</p>";
            var icon = {}; 
            if (totalfinds == 0) {   
            icon = customIcons[0]; 
            } else if (totalfinds >= 1) {   
            icon = customIcons[1];      
            } 
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({          
            map: map, 
            position: point,
            title: address,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
            }); 
            bounds.extend(point);
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
            } 
            }); 
            } 

            function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
            }

            function downloadUrl(url, callback) { 
            var request = window.ActiveXObject ? 
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : 
            new XMLHttpRequest; 

            request.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (request.readyState == 4) { 
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing; 
            callback(request, request.status); 
            } 
            }; 

            request.open('GET', url, true); 
            request.send(null); 
            } 

            function doNothing() {} 

            </script> 
            </head>    
            <body onLoad="load()">
                <div id="map"></div>
            </body> 
            </html>
```

**NEW WORKING CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>All Locations</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/alllocationsstyle.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/infobox.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var customIcons = {
            0: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            },
            1: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            }
            };

            function load() { 
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), { 
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.312195845815246,-4.45948481875007), 
            zoom:6, 
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap' 
            }); 

            // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file 
            downloadUrl("phpfile.php", function(data) { 
            var xml = data.responseXML; 
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
            var locationname = markers[i].getAttribute("locationname"); 
            var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
            var totalfinds = markers[i].getAttribute("totalfinds");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng( 
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("osgb36lat")), 
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("osgb36lon")));
            var html = locationname + "<p>" + 'No. of finds: ' + "<b>" + totalfinds + "</b>" + "</p>";
            var icon = {}; 
            if (totalfinds == 0) {   
            icon = customIcons[0]; 
            } else if (totalfinds >= 1) {   
            icon = customIcons[1];      
            } 
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({          
            map: map, 
            position: point,
            title: address,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
            }); 

            var boxText = document.createElement("div");

            boxText.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 8px; background: yellow; padding: 5px;";        
            boxText.innerHTML =  locationname + "<p>" + 'No. of finds: ' + "<b>" + totalfinds + "</b>" + "</p>";

            var myOptions = {
            content: boxText
            ,disableAutoPan: false
            ,maxWidth: 0
            ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)
            ,zIndex: null
            ,boxStyle: { 
            background: "url('tipbox.gif') no-repeat"
            ,opacity: 0.75
            ,width: "280px"
            }
            ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
            ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
            ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
            ,isHidden: false
            ,pane: "floatPane"
            ,enableEventPropagation: false
            };
            var infoBox = new InfoBox(myOptions);  
            infoBox.open(map, marker); 
            bounds.extend(point);
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            } 
            }); 
            } 

            function downloadUrl(url, callback) { 
            var request = window.ActiveXObject ? 
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : 
            new XMLHttpRequest; 

            request.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (request.readyState == 4) { 
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing; 
            callback(request, request.status); 
            } 
            }; 

            request.open('GET', url, true); 
            request.send(null); 
            } 

            function doNothing() {} 

            </script> 
            </head>    
            <body onLoad="load()">
                <div id="map"></div>
            </body> 
            </html>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you isolated the line that is getting the error. Copying and pasting your code sample is 1) a pain and 2) potentially imprecise where line numbers are concerned.

Comment: No offense taken. (My comment was a bit tough, but I didn't mean to be mean.) Still, I do not see a 'highlighted' line in the OP. Could you copy and paste it out separately plz? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a function `downloadUrl()` that you have not defined.  You need to define that function.  One way to do that would be to include this code from the original question:

```
function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for taking the time to reply to my post. In addition to your code, I realised that I hadn't been calling the 'infobox' js file. The file is now working but I'm having a little trouble with setting the bounds. As you can see in my updated code I've added: 
bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
but when I try and add bounds.extend(point); and map.fitBounds(bounds); depending where I put the code, I either get a blank map or the 'map bounds' effect doesn't work. I just wondered whether it be at all possible if you could show me where I'm going wrong please.Kind regards Chris.

Comment: I'm guessing you need to define an initial `bounds` before calling `bounds.extend()` or `map.fitBounds()`.  ` bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();` creates an empty LatLngBounds object.  You need pass it two LatLng objects representing the southwest and northeast corners of the LatLngBounds you are creating.  You can also use `bounds.isEmpty()` to check see if I'm right and this really is the problem.  Basically, it doesn't make sense to "extend" an empty rectangle.  And a map that is "fit" to an empty bounds seems likely to come up empty.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for bearing with me on this. I'm sorry to ask a dumb question, but do I keep the bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();` line in and then add the bounds.isEmpty()?
I did get the bounds part of the code to work prior to the inclusion of the InfoBox at http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/alllocations.html but I must admit it took me an absolute age to get that to work. Many thanks once again for your time, and patience. Kind regards. Chris

Comment: Yes, you need the `bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();` line because that's what creates a `LatLngBounds` object.  However, you probably want it to be `bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw,ne);` where `sw` is a `LatLng` object representing the southwest corner of the initial bounds and `ne` is a `LatLng` object representing the northeast corner of the initial bounds.

Comment: By the way, if my answer here has been helpful, it would be great if you could vote it up by clicking the upward-pointing triangle next to it.  (I see from your profile that you have never voted on any questions or answers, which makes me suspect that you may not be aware of the feature.)  This is different from accepting an answer (with the green checkmark), which you do when an answer has not just been helpful but has totally solved your problem.

Comment: Many thanks for your help & pointing out the 'Vote up', I wasn't aware of this. I've been back to my original code, & I've got it to work. There is however one issue. If I include google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
no matter which marker I click on, the InfoBox appears at the last marker (top of the map). When it's omitted the boxes are against the correct markers. Ideally I'd like the InfoBox to move as each marker is clicked, like the Infowindow, but I just can't get around it. Could you please have a look at this & let me know where I've gone wrong. Regards Chris.

Comment: I forgot to say I've updated the code at the end of my original post. Kind regards. Chris

Comment: Since this is getting pretty far away from the original question about the "missing object" error, I would recommend posting it as a new question.  More people will be likely to see it (and thus more people likely to answer) that way.